# What happened to the Sephardic Pashta?

Tags: sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, trop-cantillation

i recently got into a debate with a user here as to whether or not Pashta was a conjunctive or disjunctive accent (see [chat transcript](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/37778/2016/3/31)).

My position was based on the fact that when i was taught the te'amim, and the name of the te'amim, that there was no Pashta, but rather i was taught that there was only Qadma. This was presented as true by [the recordings put out by the Egyptian community in New York](http://www.ahaba.org/media/audio/cantors/cantorft/fst_taameh_torah.mp3) as well as a list compiled by the former Chief Rabbi of Alexandria

[image]

When that user looked into it, he found that this was indeed a common situation, where most Sephardim don't distinguish between Pashta an Qadma. This doesn't seem to be a matter of a few ba'al qorim not knowing the difference, but a lack of distinction amongst teachers and written materials. As evidenced by the Zarqa table on Wikipedia which lacks distinction

[image]

As well as this video my Moshe Chabusha (one of the leading Sephardic Cantors in the world) recording the Jerusalem Sephardic Te'amim and the Iraqi Te'amim, both of which lacking a Pashta

https://youtu.be/wh2ppJ2GzFk

Here is a page from a book that shows the different names for the trope. It shows a repetition of the Ashkenazi name Pashta, each time linking it to a Sephardi equivalent, sometimes showing it as a qadma, others as a pashta (apparently this book was written when sephardim still had a Pashta) and once as T'rei Qadmin but the t'rei qadmin is only used for a Pashta that has two trope symbols, and is otherwise called a shenei pashtin, the document shows that this Pashta is different than the earlier ones in the list as it is shown with two trope symbols above the name, whereas the others only have 1.

[image]

So my question is what happened to the Pashta in the Sephardic heritage?

Comment: Everyone please beware that while different traditions may have different names for various accents (see [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantillation#Names_in_different_traditions)), this question is about the two different notes that Ashkenazim call Kadma and Pashta _independent of what others call them to distinguish them_.

Comment: Many Ashkenazim don't know the difference either, sadly. It just is a sad fact of our reality that the Torah reading at most synagogues is grammatically sub-par :(

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes, but at least in your books it is still written as a separate entity, whereas many Sephardic Lists/Books don't have or teach any distinction at all.

Comment: That chart lists the names Azla and Kadma in the Sefardic column. If you can document 'reliable' texts which omit any distinction that would improve your question IMO. Right now it just seems the answer is: because not everyone knows grammatical subtleties.

Comment: @DoubleAA Azla only occurs in combination with Geirish. Listen to any Sephardic recording or walk into a shul and you will see this is the case

Comment: That table you include has "trei kadmin" and "kadma". Seemingly, the "trei kadmin" is what an ashkenazi would call "pashta"

Comment: The Egyptian scan is missing a Tilsha as well (what Ash. would call Tlisha Ketana). Telisha Gedola is a disjunctive and Telisha Ketana is a conjunctive. Again, it seems that they were just 'sloppy' (i don't mean that to be derogatory; many ashkenazim don't distinguish the two either, unfortunately)

Comment: @DoubleAA i believe many Ashkenazi tikkunim add an extra symbol over many words to help the reader distinguish between a pashta and qadma, but that there are actual instances of two pashtas that occur as their own trope. Like gershayim vs geirish

Comment: I've never heard of such a thing and highly doubt its existence.

Comment: @DoubleAA *shrug* It's in the wikipedia page

Comment: I further support this with the Egyptian scan putting trei kadmin right next to yetiv. A yetiv and a "pashta" are basically substitutes for each other, and both are unlike an ashkenazi "kadma".

Comment: Hey, what's the source for the image with the sheet music?  I would *love* to see the rest of the book where that came from if I can.  Thank you!

Comment: @MauroBraunstein It was sent to me by Joseph Mosseri, an Egyptian Chazazan and Sephardi researcher in NY. If you want i can ask him

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34300&st=&pgnum=74 lists both Kadma and Trei Kadmin, but says they don't count as two and the latter is just to indicate Mil'eil.

Comment: @DoubleAA So then Sephardim invented an entire new non existent ta'am and forget a real one? Even worse :( lol But yeah i had a feeling this t'rei qadmin was the same as indicating mil'eil vs milrah. Such rampant amounts of confusion

Comment: @DoubleAA i think i'll just use the normal qadma melody for qadma, and use the t'rei qadmin melody for pashta

Comment: @DoubleAA According to Pizmonim.org Qadma is a disjunctive, and says the following: qadma (“first”): precedes zaqef qaton

tere qadmin: replaces qadma when the word is not stressed on the last syllable     source: http://www.pizmonim.org/taamim.php

Comment: If it helps, as a Sephardic baal koreh, we learn the taamim of kadma and pashta as both kadma. However, even though we don't distinguish it by name, we distinguish it in stops- we continue on a kadma, but we would stop at a kadma at the end of a word, what you would cal a pashta.